# "where python" 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: path, pip, environment-variables, where-clause

When I type

```
> where python
```

or

```
> where pip
```

I get

```
> 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.
```

I have python in my PATH environment variables. Could this be an error with Windows 10?

Comment: "I have python in my PATH environment variables" - Could you share the content of your PATH environemnt variable? How did you set it?

Comment: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

I was missing system variables in path

I added:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wbem
```